# AUCTeX calls makeindex without file extension

Tags: auctex

I note that AUCTeX calls `makeindex` without file extension, e.g., `makeindex tmp` instead of `makeindex tmp.idx`. It means if there is a subdirectory with the same name as the first part of the file name `makeindex` does not see the `.idx` file producing and empty `.ind` file. Is that a bug or a feature? Shouldn't AUCTeX call makeindex with the file extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the call just sometimes, you can issue <kbd>C-u C-c C-c</kbd> `Index` <kbd>RET</kbd> (note the prefix argument <kbd>C-u</kbd> before the usual <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>) and then add on the command line the extension.

If instead you want to always change how AUCTeX runs `makeindex`, you can either customize the `Index` entry of `TeX-command-list` variable with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX-command-list` <kbd>RET</kbd> and replace `%s` with `%s.idx` in the `Command` field, or add the following code to your init file (this is the same as doing what I've said before but with just copy-&-paste)

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("Index" "makeindex %s.idx" TeX-run-index nil t
                    :help "Run makeindex to create index file")))
```